# Get the total file size from a directory for each date using map and pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, directory

I'm working on a project where the file name consists of actual dates but the data for the dates are split into multiple files.

Developed the following program to count the number of files for each date (part of the filename) and also the total size.

Is there a better way to achieve the same?

```
import os
import glob
import os
import collections
directory_name = "\\SpeicifDir\\"
# Get a list of files (file paths) in the given directory 
list_of_files = filter( os.path.isfile,
                        glob.glob(directory_name + '*.txt') )
mapOfDateFileSize = collections.defaultdict(list)
# For all the files
for file_path in list_of_files:
    file_size =  os.stat(file_path).st_size
    filename = os.path.basename(file_path)
    splitFilename = filename.split('-')
    # Extract the file and split the file using - as a separator
    dtForFile = splitFilename[1] + "-" + splitFilename[2] + "-" + splitFilename[3]
    # Get the file name and size
    if dtForFile in mapOfDateFileSize:
        dataFromDictionary = mapOfDateFileSize[dtForFile]
        dataFromDictionary = dataFromDictionary[0]
        totalCount = dataFromDictionary[0]
        totalSize =  dataFromDictionary[1]
        totalCount = totalCount + 1 
        totalSize = totalSize + file_size
        # Update the file size and count
        mapOfDateFileSize[dtForFile] = [ (totalCount, totalSize) ]
    else:
        mapOfDateFileSize[dtForFile].append((1,file_size))

# For each date get the total size, total file count
for dt,elements in mapOfDateFileSize.items():
    dataFromDictionary = elements[0]
    totalCount = dataFromDictionary[0]
    totalSize =  dataFromDictionary[1]
    print (dt, ",", totalCount , ",", totalSize)
```

Comment: "better" in what sense? You also need to clearly specify the filename formatting. Your question might be better suited to [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @nsivakr can you provide the sample filename format

Comment: @deadshot, the filename is Output-2021-11-10-Count (1,2,3,4,etc.,)

Comment: @martineau, Thanks. Will do.